# React typescript conditional types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a hook that returns `data`. Its type is depending on the props passed.

```
interface MyHookProps<T, TF> {
  transform?: (data: T) => TF
}

const myHook = <T extends any = any, TF = any>(props?: MyHookProps<T, TF>) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  return { data: items }
}
```

I want my `data` to be the return type of `transform` when it is passed as prop and `T` when its not

example:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const { data } = myHook<User[]>();
```

Its type should be `User[]`, but when you do it like this:

```
const { data } = myHook<User[]>({
  transform: (data) => data.map(d => ({ ...d, another: 1 }))
})
```

Its type should be

```
{
  name: string;
  age: number;
  another: string;
}[]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible as written in the question as TypeScript lacks partial type inference. Providing an explicit type parameter will *prevent* inference of others.

We can use currying to work around this problem.

```
const myHook = <T extends any>() => <TF extends any>(props?: MyHookProps<T, TF>) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  return { data: items } as { data: unknown extends TF ? T : TF }
}
```

Here we "chain" two functions together. The first one uses `T` as the generic type while the second one can *infer* `TF`. In the conditional type at the return statement, we check if `TF` could be inferred. If not, we return `T`.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

namespace N1 {
  const { data } = myHook<User[]>()();
}

namespace N2 {
  const { data } = myHook<User[]>()({
    transform: (data) => data.map(d => ({ ...d, another: 1 }))
  })
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8ASB7bBrABSmwAcBnAHgBUAaZKgMQD5kBvAKGWTCjhDJjYoAWwD8ALmQAKACZwwcSVQCUyALwtG7AL7t2CbPzDJhWXHnXJqyCAA9IIGWWR90TKao1XGN+xEfOru4kxOQSaGb4RKSUtPTMniwcXAZGyADawJDCZHRkEGAAktlkALqWAK75AMoKkFLppcp6XFAFFVAgbMhyCpJZEDnI2i7OrD3yisgVIHgg2ADuXXYOTvHIovTISgzDOnqgkLCIKACq+VBsnMggcMIQkmQ8oADmANzXcC8PNxXCAEbQD66di3e5kEgnZAAOQAjFcUoYnt1enBhpZTDh8BRztBGu5lB5gXowRAIVDoQAmBHIVLI8ao9FqEyRPA4i74jxSZJcbi8fiCESSWSTRITBQAOmEcBIsnULG5yAlypkdD42DAAAtoJJ4dplM0uPr9kA)